# Convert int to float: how it is done

Tags: c++, c, casting, type-conversion

I'm new to C programming language, and I'd like to ask a question.

Integer i here is casting to float then f (somehow) successfully represents 5.0:

```
int i = 5;
float f = i;   //Something happened here...
```

However if we try this approach:

```
int i = 5;
float f = *(float *)&i;
```

f would NOT get 5.0 since it interprets the bits stored in i in "float's way". So what magic the complier actually does in the first case? It seems a quite effort-taking job... Can someone specify that? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It is an effort-taking job, but any CPU that has floating-point support will provide an instruction that does it.

If you had to convert a 2's complement `int` to IEEE float format for yourself, you would:

- take the integer base-2 log (closely related to the index of the highest set bit), which gives you the exponent. Offset this and store it in the exponent bits of the float.
- copy the top `n` bits of the int (starting from the bit *after* the first set non-sign bit) into the significand of the float. `n` is however many bits of significand there are in a `float` (23 for a 32 bit single-precision float). If there are any remaining bits in the `int` (that is, if it's greater than 2<sup>24</sup>), and the next bit after the ones you have room for is `1`, you may or may not round up depending on the IEEE rounding mode in operation.
- copy the sign bit from the `int` to the `float`.

Comment: That is fine for the mantissa, you need to add that the exponent needs to be computed

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the assembly

```
    int i = 5;
000D139E  mov         dword ptr [i],5  
    float f = i;
000D13A5  fild        dword ptr [i]  
000D13A8  fstp        dword ptr [f]
```

**[fild](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-135/index.html)** is what does the magic

Comment: it pragmatically answers the question `what magic the complier actually does` with a good link, +1.

Answer (score 3):

convert int bits to float

```
float IntBitsToFloat(long long int bits)
{
    int sign     = ((bits & 0x80000000) == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int exponent = ((bits & 0x7f800000) >> 23);
    int mantissa =  (bits & 0x007fffff);

    mantissa |= 0x00800000;
   // Calculate the result:
   float f = (float)(sign * mantissa * Power(2, exponent-150));
   return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the IA32 systems, the compiler would generate the following:-

```
fild dword ptr [i] ; load integer in FPU register, I believe all 32bit integers can be represented exactly in an FPU register
fstp dword ptr [f] ; store fpu register to RAM, truncating/rounding to 32 bits, so the value may not be the same as i
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic depends on your platform.

One possibility is that your CPU has a special instruction to copy floating point numbers into integral registers.

Of course someone has to design these CPUs, so this is not really an explanation for the algorithm at hand.

A platform might be using a floating point format that goes like this (actually, this is a fixed-point format for the sake of example):

```
[sIIIIFFFF]
```

where `s` is the sign, the `I`s are the part before the dot, the `F`s are the part after the dot, e.g. (dot is virtual and only for presentation)

```
 -  47.5000
[sIIII.FFFF]
```

in this case conversion is almost trivial and can be implemented using bitshifting:

```
    -47.5000
 >> 4
 ---------------
    -47
```

And like in this example, commodity C++ implementations use a floating point representation often referred to as [IEEE Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), see also [IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). These are more complicated than fixed-point numbers, as they really designate a simple formula of the form _s*m<sup>n</sup>, however, they *have* a well defined interpretation and you can unfold them into something more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just compiled the code in question under VC++ and looked at the disassembly:

```
   int i = 5;
00A613BE  mov         dword ptr [i],5 

   float f = i;
00A613C5  fild        dword ptr [i] 
00A613C8  fstp        dword ptr [f]
```

First assembly statement moves 5 into the memory represented by i. Second statement, fild, converts the memory represented by i into a floating point number and pushes it onto the FPU stack. The third statement, fstp, takes the memory on the FPU stack and moves it to f.

Comment: how about explaining it a little bit? mention what this code does and I guarantee at least one upvote :)

Comment: First assembly statement moves 5 into the memory represented by i.  Second statement, fild, converts the memory represented by i into a floating point number and pushes it onto the FPU stack.  The third statement, fstp, takes the memory on the FPU stack and moves it to f.

Comment: +1 for the comment, but how about adding this information to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In almost all modern systems, the specification for floating point arithmetic is the IEEE754 standard. This details everything from layout in memory to how truncation and rounding is propagated. It's a big area and someting you quite often need to take detailed account of in scientific and engineering programming.